# Combining multiple While loops into one

Tags: wordpress, while-loop

I am working on integrating the Nivo Slider in to a WordPress page, I wanted to use it with captions and eventually go the code to work as shown below;

```
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider"> 

        <?php 

        $slides = array (
            'post_type'      => 'slides',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
        );

        $count=1;

        $slideshow = new WP_Query( $slides ); 

        while ( $slideshow->have_posts() ) : $slideshow->the_post(); ?>

            <?php $feat_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ); ?>

            <a href="<?php the_field('slide_link'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $feat_image_url; ?>" alt="<?php echo the_title(); ?>" title="#htmlcaption<?php echo $count ?>"/></a>

            <?php $count++; ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div>

        <?php

        $count=1;

        while ( $slideshow->have_posts() ) : $slideshow->the_post(); ?>

            <div id="htmlcaption<?php echo $count ?>" class="nivo-html-caption">
                <strong>This</strong> is an example of a <em>HTML</em> caption with <a href="#">a link</a>.
            </div>

            <?php $count++; ?>

        <?php endwhile;

        wp_reset_query(); ?>

</div>
```

I am concerned that I have unnecessarily added 2 While loops and counters. Is there a way to make this more efficient by means of combining the loops and only using one counter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following, using a temporary var for the captions and output it after the loop:

```
$captions = '';
while ( $slideshow->have_posts() ) : $slideshow->the_post(); ?>
    <?php $feat_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_field('slide_link'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $feat_image_url; ?>" alt="<?php echo the_title(); ?>" title="#htmlcaption<?php echo $count ?>"/></a>
    <php $captions .= '<div id="htmlcaption' . $count . '" class="nivo-html-caption"><strong>This</strong> is an example of a <em>HTML</em> caption with <a href="#">a link</a></div>'; ?>
    <?php $count++; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Then in place of your second loop just do:

```
echo $captions;
```